# Excel VBA VLOOKUP in Colunm

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, macros

I have a sheet for monthly report. When daily report got, I want a VLOOKUP formula to be entered under the column where the date exist.

I have already set the sheets up with the VLOOKUP formulas entered into the adjacent cells, but their is still have program. I don’t know how to add loop formula to add another column for another days. Now I am trying to find the way on Google, but it doesn’t work. So please help if you know.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Help us to help you: **post your current code.**